# HTML Canvas Scratcher, reveal a div when percentage of image is scratched

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm using this script I found for a scratch card type effect (from http://beej.us/blog/data/html-canvas-scratcher-2/). What code would I need to add, in order to show a hidden div once a certain percentage (say 70%) of the image is "scratched out".
Thanks.

```
**
 * This file controls the page logic
 *
 * depends on jQuery>=1.7
 */
(function() {

/**
 * Returns true if this browser supports canvas
 *
 * From http://diveintohtml5.info/
 */
function supportsCanvas() {
    return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
};

/**
 * Handle scratch event on a scratcher
 */
function scratcher1Changed(ev) {
    // Test every pixel. Very accurate, but might be slow on large
    // canvases on underpowered devices:
    //var pct = (scratcher.fullAmount() * 100)|0;

    // Only test every 32nd pixel. 32x faster, but might lead to
    // inaccuracy:
    var pct = (this.fullAmount(32) * 100)|0;

    $('#scratcher1Pct').html('' + pct + '%');
};

/**
 * Reset all scratchers
 */
function onResetClicked(scratchers) {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < scratchers.length; i++) {
        scratchers[i].reset();
    }

    return false;
};

/**
 * Assuming canvas works here, do all initial page setup
 */
function initPage() {
    var scratcherLoadedCount = 0;
    var scratchers = [];
    var i, i1;

    // called each time a scratcher loads
    function onScratcherLoaded(ev) {
        scratcherLoadedCount++;

        if (scratcherLoadedCount == scratchers.length) {
            // all scratchers loaded!

            // bind the reset button to reset all scratchers
            $('#resetbutton').on('click', function() {
                    onResetClicked(scratchers);
                });

            // hide loading text, show instructions text
            $('#loading-text').hide();
            $('#inst-text').show();
        }
    };

    // create new scratchers
    var scratchers = new Array(1);

    for (i = 0; i < scratchers.length; i++) {
        i1 = i + 1;
        scratchers[i] = new Scratcher('scratcher' + i1);

        // set up this listener before calling setImages():
        scratchers[i].addEventListener('imagesloaded', onScratcherLoaded);
        scratchers[i].setImages('images/s' + i1 + 'bg.jpg',
            'images/s' + i1 + 'fg.gif');
    }

    // get notifications of this scratcher changing
    // (These aren't "real" event listeners; they're implemented on top
    // of Scratcher.)
    scratchers[0].addEventListener('reset', scratcher1Changed);
    scratchers[0].addEventListener('scratch', scratcher1Changed);

    // Or if you didn't want to do it every scratch (to save CPU), you
    // can just do it on 'scratchesended' instead of 'scratch':
    //scratchers[2].addEventListener('scratchesended', scratcher3Changed);
};

/**
 * Handle page load
 */
$(function() {
    if (supportsCanvas()) {
        initPage();
    } else {
        $('#scratcher-box').hide();
        $('#lamebrowser').show();
    }
});

})();
```

Comment: Check the percentage in the javascript `if(percentage >= 70){document.getElementById('show').style.display = "block"}` Having that at the end of your script should work.

Comment: thanks jack - having no luck though- I added that to the script, as well as a div id="show" to the html (with a style of display:none in the css). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Create a JS fiddle and I'll look at it again.

Comment: I've added a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MT4nK/9/   - thanks

Comment: Answered the question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MT4nK/11/

You already had this:

```
<div class="hidden" id="show">This div to appear after 40% scracthed</div>
```

I added this to your CSS:

```
.show{
    display:block;   
}
```

And this to your javascript:

```
function scratcher1Changed(ev) {
        // Test every pixel. Very accurate, but might be slow on large
        // canvases on underpowered devices:
        //var pct = (scratcher.fullAmount() * 100)|0;

        // Only test every 32nd pixel. 32x faster, but might lead to
        // inaccuracy:
        var pct = (this.fullAmount(32) * 100) | 0;

        $('#scratcher1Pct').html('' + pct + '%');
        //*******************
        if(pct >= 40){
            $('#show').addClass( "show" )
        }
        //*************** Added This...

    };
```

EDIT****

You'll also need to set the class back to `hidden` when you reset FYI.